# Can I use something along the lines of String#constantize to initialize a Hyperstack::Component?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, isomorphic, hyperstack

I have some objects in my DB that I like to render with a dedicated Hyperstack view Component.
Lets say my objects have a unique `name` property from A to J. Now I would like to loop through them with `each` and render a `ComponentA`, `ComponentB`, `ComponentC`, ... depending on the `name` of my object, and pass my object as a param to the component.

What I do now is:

```rb
DB_Objects.each do |object|
  if    object.name == 'A'
    ComponentA(data: object)
  elsif object.name == 'B'
    ComponentB(data: object)
  elsif object.name == 'C'
    ComponentC(data: object)
  elsif ...
```

What I want to do is something like:

```rb
DB_Objects.each do |object|
  ('Component' + object.name).constantize(data: object)
end
```

This is pseudo code as you can't give variables to constantize.
But it shows what I would like to do.

How can I prevent a manual mapping of a object to its view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every component class defines a method of the same name as the class.  When you say for example

```
ComponentA(data: object)
```

you are calling a method named `ComponentA` that is tied the the ComponentA class.

So to dynamically reference the component you would use the `send` method:

```
send('Component' + object.name, data: object)
```

Alternatively each component class has a class method `insert_element` which will render an instance of the component class, and insert it into the rendering buffer.  For example:

```
('Component' + object.name).constantize.insert_element(data: object)
```

I bring this up because while it is longer, you could use it to generalize this idea of yours (which I think is pretty cool)

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  def render(opts = {})
    ('Component' + object.name).constantize.insert_element(opts, data: object)
  end
end
```

Now you can say

```
some_record.render
```

Of course to generalize it like this you might want to use something other than `name`.  Anyway you could really have fun with this !

Answer (score 2):

Never used HyperStack, but this should give you the right idea.

```
class Thing < ApplicationRecord
  OBJECT_TYPES = { 'A': 'CommponentA' }.freeze

  def to_component
    @to_component ||= OBJECT_TYPES[self.name].constantize.new(self)
  end 
end
```

You could just `"Component#{self.name}".constantize.new(self)` but I've found that to be rather confusing to other developers when they jump in on a project.

Keep in mind `String#constantize` will return the actual constant, and not just a string that's constantized (camelcased and what have you) so you can call `#new` or `#call` or whatever you want on it.

Comment: This would almost work.  The problem is `new` only creates a component but does not actually render it.  You would have to use the `insert_element` method instead of new.  Otherwise pretty good answer for somebody who never used Hyperstack :-)